# How to Add/Replace Images to a Div

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have HTML line items (in a left column) with words I'll use to decide which image to display in another div (center column).
Here's a line item example:

```
<li><a href="" onClick="showPic(this.innerHTML)">pngName</a></li>
```

The center div reads:

```
<div id="fcenter"></div>
```

In my javascript I write:

```
function showPic(picName) {
   var img = new Image();
   img.src = '/pics/'+picName+'.png';  // get name 
   var middlePanel = document.getElementById("fcenter");
   img.onload = function() {
      middlePanel.appendChild(img);
   };
}
```

It won't display although I have the right image name and it's pointing to the right file source.

Comment: `img.onload = function() {Keep this}` remove the rest

Answer (score 0):

The `img.onload` function is never going to run because the image hasn't yet been displayed. To save energy, the browser only loads images that are displayed. So you can't wait for the image to load when you haven't yet displayed it.

Here is the updated function...

```
function showPic(picName) {
   var img = new Image();
   img.src = '/pics/'+picName+'.png';  // get name 
   var middlePanel = document.getElementById("fcenter");
   middlePanel.appendChild(img);
}
```

Once the image is showing, the browser will start to load it. If you want, you can run the `img.onload` after the image has been added to the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you trying to do this entirely in Javascript? This would be a situation in which you would handle the click event in Javascript and the image should be accessed by a line or two of CSS implemented into your Javascript. Here is an example:

HTML

```
<div id="fcenter">
  <li><a href="#" onClick="showPic()">pngName</a></li>  
<div>
```

Javascript

```
function showPic() {
  var el = document.querySelector("#fcenter");

  el.style.backgroundImage = "url('')";
}
```

I hope this helps you fix your problem. If not tell me and I'll try to work it out with you.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `img.onload = function() {...}` but keep the `middlePanel.appendChild(img)`. When you are waiting for `img` to `load`, being loaded includes actually being appended to DOM as well, your event handler will never happen because `img` never gets appended to the DOM. Also, use `.textContent` instead of `.innerHTML` if you just want the text, it's cleaner.

### Demo

```js
function showPic(picName) {
  var img = new Image();
  img.src = 'http://lorempixel.com/100/100/' + picName;
  var middlePanel = document.getElementById("fcenter");
  middlePanel.appendChild(img);
}
```

```css
main {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

img {
  display: inline-block
}

ul {
  font: 400 32px/2 Consolas;
  width: 30%;
  list-style: none
}

section {
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#/" onClick="showPic(this.textContent)">people</a></li>

    <li><a href="#/" onClick="showPic(this.textContent)">animals</a></li>
  </ul>
  <section id="fcenter"></section>
</main>
```